# Cannot set property 'render' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I got problem with vuejs, please help me

I have main.js:

```js
    import App from './App.vue'
    import routes from './app.router';
        Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
        
        new Vue({
            el:'#app',
            render: h => h(App),
            created(){
            },
            router: routes,
            methods:{
        
            }
        })
```

My file App.vue:

```js
    <template>
        <div id="app" class="">
            <menu-header> </menu-header>
            <router-view> </router-view>
        </div>
    </template>
    
    
    <script>
    import menuHeader from './components/layout/menu-header.vue'; // error when i import this component
    components:{
        menuHeader
    }
    </script>
```

This is my menu-header.vue:

```js
     <template>
        <ul>
            <li>
                Hello           
            </li>
        </ul>
     </template>
    
     <script>
     export default {
        name: "menuHeader"
     };
    
     </script>
```

My problem is when i add menu-header component, my page give me error:

> Cannot set property 'render' of undefined

But if I don't, it run normally. Please explain why and help me fix it.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like you are not exporting Vue component definition properly from `App.vue` file:

```js
<template>
    <div id="app" class="">
        <menu-header> </menu-header>
        <router-view> </router-view>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    import MenuHeader from './components/layout/menu-header.vue'; // error when I import this component

    // Code is missing export
    export default {
        components: {
            MenuHeader
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I forgot export Vue component. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Same here. Thanks Harshal. It turns out that the vue-cli(v3) dev env doesn't mind a component without any JS code, but the prod bundle does.

Comment: Is there no other way of adding components to App.vue without exporting App.vue? Is it ok to export App.vue?

Comment: @SeanKPS, unfortunately, no. Imagine `.vue` file to be a gluing mechanism to stitch two independent files - template and js. So only when you export something, other files can see it. Thus it is necessary. And it is ok to export from `App.vue` file.